# Как работать без наследования

Tags: c#

Есть класс A, от него наследуется класс B. Как сделать, чтобы если убрать наследование, мы все еще могли получить доступ к методу A, не меняя код в Main.

```
class A
{
    public void F1() { System.Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}

class B //: A
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B objB = new B();
        objB.F1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Композиция.(адаптер)
Если по простому: внутри класса B сделать метод, который вызывает метод класса A.

Comment: `class B { void F1(){ new A().F1(); }  }` ?